# Count of nodes in BST

Tags: visual-c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to count the number of nodes in a Binary Search Tree and was wondering what the most efficient means was. These are the options that I have found:

1. store int count in the BST Class
2. store int children in each node of the tree which stores the number of children under it
3. write a method that counts the number of Nodes in the BST

if using option 3, I've written:

```
int InOrder {
    Node *cur = root;
    int count = 0;
    Stack *s = null;
    bool done = false;

    while(!done) {
        if(cur != NULL) {
            s.push(cur);
            cur = cur->left;
        }
        else {
            if(!s.IsEmpty()) {
                cur = s.pop();
                count++;
                cur = cur->right;
            }
            else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
```

}

but from looking at it, it seems like it would get stuck in an infinite loop between `cur = cur->left;` and `cur = cur->right;`

So which option is the most efficient and if it is option 3, then will this method work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first option is the quickest and it only requires O(1) space to achieve this. However whenever you insert/delete an item, you need to keep updating this value.
It will take O(1) time to get the number of all the nodes.

The second option would make this program way too complicated since deleting/inserting a node somewhere would have to update all of its ancestors. Either you add a parent pointer so you can adequately update each one of the ancestors, or you need to go through all the nodes in the tree and update the numbers again. Anyway I think this would be the worst option of all three.

The third option is good if you don't call this many times since the first option is a lot quicker, O(1), than this option. This will take O(n) since you need to go through every single node to check the count.

In terms of your code, I think it's easier to write in a recursive way like below:

```
int getCount(Node* n)
{
 if (!n)
  return 0;
 return 1 + getCount(n->left) + getCount(n->right);
}
```

Hope this helps!